# Which Java collection are best to populate one to many data from Database and work on?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-7, java-6

Which Java Collection is best in following scenario?

1) Getting very huge data in single SQL Query from 3 tables in Java.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3;
```

2) Need to assign result set into three different collections.

```
Collection<Table1> 
Collection<Table2> 
Collection<Table3>
```

3) Relate the data :

```
Table Relations:

Table 1.PrimaryKey have multiple rows (0 - n) in Table2.ForeignKey
Collection<Table2>.contains(Table1).fetchAllRecords()

Table 1.PrimaryKey have multiple rows (0-n) in Table3.ForeignKey
Collection<Table3>.contains(Table1).fetchAllRecords()

Table 3.PrimaryKey have multiple rows(0-n) in Table 2.ForeignKey
Collection<Table2>.contains(Table3).fetchAllRecords()
```

4) Populate it into single object say ACCOUNT_DETAILS having all properties from all 3 objects.

I have created three POJO; say Table1, Table2 and Table3; with all property names same as of Column names.

Which Java 6 collection should i use for "EASY TRAVERSE AND COMPARE"? Any collection provided by Apache Commons for same?

Will List of  Object be fine or some better object we have?

Comment: Arraylist will be fine